# How top pop last element of ActiveRelation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have this query:

```
red_houses = user.houses.where(color: 'red')
```

How can I pop the last element of `red_houses`?

I know I can do this `red_houses[1..-2]`, but not `red_houses.pop`, is there any way I am missing?

Basically I want to delete the last element and get the remaining relation without the last element on it.

Comment: Do you want to delete last element?, Are you looking something like `red_houses.last`?

Comment: I want to delete the last element to get the remaining of the relation without the last element.

Comment: You can use either `red_houses.delete(red_houses.last)` or `red_houses.delete_at(red_houses.size-1)`, after this if you check `red_houses` will on have last element, but this will remove only last element form `red_houses` and not from database

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods to remove records from an association: [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-delete) and [destroy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-destroy). Both of them can be called with the object you want to remove or its id. (Also you can use a list of object or a list of ids as parameters).

Since `:delete` works according the strategy specified by the `:dependent` option (with default of nullify), `:destroy` always remove the records from the database, ignoring the `:dependent` option.

But, if you don't want to persist at the db that action. Before remove, you need a working variable (calling `:to_a`), and then you can call `pop`:

```
red_houses = user.houses.where(color: 'red').to_a
red_houses.pop
```